# Fos Rest View response

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jms-serializer

I use

```
"name": "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle",
"version": "1.7.7",

"name": "jms/serializer-bundle",
"version": "0.13.0"
```

When my response contains a word in Cyrilic, I the response like this:

```
return View::create()
->setStatusCode(200)
->setData($response)
->setSerializationContext(
    SerializationContext::create()
        ->setGroups(array('my_group'))
);
```

I get an error:

```
{
    "message": "Your data could not be encoded because it contains invalid UTF8 characters.",
    "class": "RuntimeException",
    "trace": [
      {
        "namespace": "",
        "short_class": "",
        "class": "",
        "type": "",
        "function": "",
        "file": "/home/ivan/host/aog-code/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 36,
        "args": []
      },
```

`$response` is array, but I find problem I have bad symbhol after `$rest = substr("abcdef", -1);` when I using `$shortName = $entity->getFirstName() . ($last ? ' ' . ' ' . preg_replace("/^([a-zа-я]).*$/isu", "$1", trim($last)) . '.' : '');` have norm sumbhol and have response without error
I can not understand why this happens.

Comment: are you using doctrine, is your `$response` variable a string or an object?

Comment: `$response` is array, but I find problem I have bad symbhol after `$rest = substr("abcdef", -1);` when I using `$shortName = $entity->getFirstName() . ($last ? ' ' . ' ' . preg_replace("/^([a-zа-я]).*$/isu", "$1", trim($last)) . '.' : '');` have norm sumbhol and have response without error